# Trouble with Android hybrid_local app Authentication

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, jquerymobile, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I'm developing Android hybrid_local app with the forcedroid sdk. I have two questions hope you can kindly help me out.

- It's always asking to send verification code in the auth process
  which I need to stop for ease of the user
- When app is idle for a long
  time and use back, it gets stuck looks like
  `salesforceSessionRefreshed` function in `index.html` is not working
  correctly. If I logout and login it works.

If I'm missing some configurations where I need to look and setup them? Any help would highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Madhura

Answer (score 4):

A) Use the Ray Dehler method to whitelist all IP addresses. The IP in question is your public IP not local IP so it does not matter whether you are using dynamic IP, DHCP or whatever. Your public IP never changes so Ray Dehler method works well. This will ensure that your users never get asked for a verification code. If you do not wish to whitelist all IP, you can whitelist public IPs of Internet providers in the designated area - such information is readily available.

B) If this is consistently reproducible at your end, raise it as a bug on the Github Force.com Android [Mobile SDK repo](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-android/issues?state=open)

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation @Gaurav, I'll try out these

Answer (score 0):

The second issue is because of the SDK is calling an incorrect error function at line 336 of cordova.force.js. The the error function call back has been used as `error` where it should be `fail`. This is in v2.1 and this has been fixed in v2.2